# SQL counter variable @Count += 1

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, counter

I would like to know if it's possible to create a Count variable like you would in C#.

```
DECLARE @Count Int
SET @Count = 0

--something happens
SET @Count += 1

--something happens
SET @Count += 1

IF @Count < 3
BEGIN
--Do something
END
```

Comment: Yes, using the traditional `x = x + 1` syntax.  What's the purpose?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In *SQL-Server* you can do It in following:

```
SET @count = @count + 1
```

Comment: Thanks, was surprised when nothing on sql counter searches showed me this. But thanks, back to basics :)

Comment: sure have to wait 7 min still.

Answer (score 4):

In **SQL Server 2008+** your code is perfectly valid:

```
DECLARE @Count INT;
SET @Count = 0;

PRINT @Count;
SET @Count += 1;

PRINT @Count;
SET @Count += 1;

IF @Count < 3
BEGIN
  PRINT @Count;
END
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/382140)**</kbd>

With version before 2008 you can use full syntax:

```
SET @Count = @Count + 1;
```

**[`+= operator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc627392(v=sql.120).aspx)**

> Adds two numbers and sets a value to the result of the operation. For
>   example, if a variable @x equals 35, then @x += 2 takes the original
>   value of @x, add 2 and sets @x to that new value (37).

Comment: [+=](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc627392(v=sql.120).aspx) works from SQL-Server2008 on, i'm on 2005 and didn't know it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possibile:

```
DECLARE @Count AS INTEGER
SET @Count = 0

SET @Count = @Count + 1
SET @Count = @Count + 1
SET @Count = @Count + 1

PRINT @Count --3
```